# In laravel, how can i pass a multidimensional array as an option for artisan command?

Tags: php, laravel, command-line, console, laravel-artisan

I'm trying to run laravel command "php artisan set:fields" in cmd.
How can i pass an array in command ??

```
namespace App\Console\Commands\Scripts;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use App\User;

class SetFields extends Command {

   protected $signature = 'set:fields {user_id} {--data_array=*}';
   protected $description = '';

   public function __construct() {
      parent::__construct();
   }

   public function handle() {

       $user_id = $this->argument('user_id');
       $metafield_array = $this->option('data_array');
       ....
       code_is_here
   }
 }
```

I have an array

```
$data = [
         ["key"=>"key1","value"=>1],
         ["key"=>"key2","value"=>2], 
         ["key"=>"key3","value"=>3]
        ];

Artisan::call('set:fields', [
        'user_id' => 1,
        '--data_array' => $data
    ]);
```

it's working.
But i want to run this command in cmd, how can i pass an array in command?

Comment: Maybe json encoding the array, pass the json string in the command line and decode it back to array?

Comment: It's throws an error 'Too many arguments, expected arguments "command"  "user_id" "data_array" '. It may be happens due to many special characters in encoded array.

Comment: I just encode array and then base64 encode it and other side decode it. It’s work 

Answer (score -1):

As per [RavindraPatel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10133570)'s self answer in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56494612/in-laravel-how-can-i-pass-a-multidimensional-array-as-an-option-for-artisan-com/70382941#comment99596806_56494612)

> I just encode array and then base64 encode it and other side decode it. It’s work  – Ravindra Patel